# Add the value of two different specific csv columns

Tags: python, csv

So I currently get a .csv file that looks like this:

```
HostType,Number
Windows_Desktop,84
Linux_Desktop,12
Windows_Desktop,60
Linux_Desktop,7
```

I am trying to write a script that performs a function based on the total value. So I have a two global variables:

```
WINDOWS = 0
LINUX = 0
```

I am trying to make it so that the function adds the two Window_Desktop numbers together, and Linux_Desktop numbers together. So something like..

```
def count_function():
    global WINDOWS
    global LINUX
    count_file = open('counts.csv', 'rb')
    reader = csv.reader(count_file)
    WINDOWS = float(row[2]) + float(otherrow[2])
    LINUX = float(row[2]) + float(otherrow[2])
```

(I know this is very wrong syntax, just a brief example of what I am trying to figure out)
But I don't know how to specify column and row I want to add together. They are always in the same place. Windows is always 2 and 4, Linux is always in 3 and 5. So I don't need to regex them by any means. I am just trying to figure out how to do Row 2 Column 2 + Row 4 Column 2.

Basically, I am ultimately trying to do something like:

```
if WINDOWS < 80
    some_function()
```

Although I have that part figured out, its getting the numbers to add up that I can't seem to figure out despite how many times I bash my head.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to identify the type of thing you are collecting by analyzing the contents of the first column. Since you are collecting `Windows` and `Linux` totals, you can use a dictionary to collect these data.

Try this version:

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

data = defaultdict(float)  # this just means, the default value of a key
                           # that doesn't exit is a float

with open('yourfile.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(f)  # This will skip the header
    for row in reader:
       data[row[0].split('_')[0].strip()] += float(row[1])

if data['Windows'] < 80:
   print('Do stuff')

for key, value in data.iteritems():
   print('Value for {} is {}'.format(key, value))
```

Comment: Sorry for a late response, but what you said worked perfectly, thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend using the [Pandas package](http://pandas.pydata.org/). It is very useful for working with csv files.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("/Users/daddy30000/Dropbox/Stackoverflow/16_06_20_example.csv")

windows = df[df['HostType'] == 'Windows_Desktop'].sum()[1]
linux = df[df['HostType'] == 'Linux_Desktop'].sum()[1]

print windows
>>> 144
print linux
>>> 19
```

Note that I am assuming all your Windows rows have the same spelling, 'Windows_Desktop'. You use two different spellings in the example.

Answer (score 1):

One way you can do it is like so:

```
with open("/tmp/foo.txt", 'r') as input_file:
    counts = {}
    for line in input_file:
        split_line = line.split(",")
        device = split_line[0]
        counts[device] = int(split_line[1]) + (counts.get(device) or 0)

    print counts  ## prints {'Windows_Desktop': 144, 'Linux_Desktop': 19}
```

There are many ways, but this one doesn't require imports or downloading anything new to Python

Answer (score 1):

For such as small dataset, I'd read the whole thing into memory and use indices (slightly different from yours) to directly access the proper rows and columns. I also see no need for using `global` variables (or why you're using `float` instead of `int`):

```
import csv

def count_desktops(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as count_file:
        data = list(csv.reader(count_file))
        windows = float(data[1][1]) + float(data[3][1])
        linux = float(data[2][1]) + float(data[4][1])
        return windows, linux

windows, linux = count_desktops('counts.csv')

if windows < 80:
    some_function()
```